# Preg match based on date

Tags: php, regex

I have the following code from a plugin to check a date:

```
$check_date = (preg_match("/^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})$/sim", $_REQUEST['date']))?1:0;
```

I want the date format like this to be ok:
`mm/dd/yy`

How can I update the `preg_match` to allow this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To immediately answer your question:

`$check_date = (preg_match("~^\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2}$~", $_REQUEST['date']))?1:0;`

One thing I would like to point out though is that while it will match for a mm/dd/yy value, it will not match for a valid date range (but neither did your original!). For example 99/99/99 will match.